# Javascript Not Running Where ever I Put it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've made a script work already but then when I try to add another one, it just won't run. I tried placing it everywhere the other people here says so (before  tag), but it won't work. So I was wondering it there might be a problem. It's an HTML code inside a PHP file so I thought there might be problems there? I tried window.onload but it wouldn't work as well. I'm running out on ideas so I had to ask here. Thanks to whoever will be able to point out where I'm wrong.

Here's my current code :

```
<html>
<body>

    <div class="first-row" bordercolor="yellow">
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <script>
    function UpdateRecord() {
    var userid = '.$userid.';
    var logid = '.$row['spotid'].';

          $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"spotlightcount.php",
                data:{ userid: userid, logid: logid },
                success:function () {

                }

            });
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    var timeleft = 15;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<span id=" + "clicklink" + ">" + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbspWatch the ad for " + timeleft + " more seconds! Feel free to look around! Or</font> <a href=" + "members.php" + "><font color=" + "white" + ">>Skip login ad!<</font></a></span>";
  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<span id=" + "linkclick" +">&nbsp&nbsp&nbspYou have been given 10 credits and 10 response points! <a href=" + "members.php" + "><font color=" + "yellow" + ">>Click here to go to members area!<</font></a><font color=" + "white" + "> or</font> <a href=" + "loginad.php" + "><font color=" + "yellow" + ">>Reserve your own login ad!<</font></a></span> ";
    UpdateRecord();
  }
}, 1000);

    </script>
    </div>
<div id="second-row" class="second-row">
  <iframe id="loginad" src="'.$row['adurl'].'"></iframe>
</div>
<script> (This part doesn't work)
document.getElementById("second-row").onclick = function(e){
  alert("click");
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="fitty.min.js"></script>
<script>
fitty("#clicklink");
fitty("#linkclick");
</script>
</body></html>
```

As seen on the code, I placed "This part doesn't work" where the script won't run whatever I do. Maybe you guys can help me out and make it work? I want to be able to capture a click event for my div.

Comment: Please check my answer and use the dev-tools of your browser. The error console will give you valuable information about things that are going wrong in your js. For PHP errors see the log files.

Answer (score 1):

To use PHP variables inside HTML or javascript code parts use

```
<?= $variable ?>
```

In your code for example:

```
function UpdateRecord() {
  var userid = '<?=$userid?>';
  var logid = '<?=$row["spotid"]?>';
  ...
}
```

To use quotes inside a string you can either mix single and double quotes (best choose one and stick with it):

```
var strSingleInDouble = "<span id='clicklink'>";
var strDoubleInSingle = '<span id="clicklink">';
```

or escape the inner quotes like that:

```
var strEscaped = "<span id=\"clicklink\">";
```

If *clicklink* would be a javascript variable, then don't use any quotes for it.

```
var varInStr = "<span id=" + clicklink + ">";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add " " to spotid and there is a some problem in $.ajax because you cannot use $.ajax in javascript file

```
var logid = '.$row["spotid"].';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "spotlightcount.php",
    data: { userid: userid, logid: logid },
    success: function () {
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry about that I check that in my browser but other files is not in my directory.Please don't downvote my comment because it's a real mistake because of other files are not in my directory